# How to draw four subplots with a double y-axis plot in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have successfully drawn the four subplots. Later, I wanted on of the subplot to have double yy plot (one x axis and two y axis plot). After a series of trials by adding new code , I did got it. But, problem is, a fifth empty plot has popped up. Please, check below screen shot. 
[image]

Required part of My code is given below:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 10))
fig, add_ax = plt.subplots()
plt.rc('font',family='Times New Roman')        
.
.
# yy axis plot in fourth subplot
add_ax = axs[1][1].twinx()
axs[1][1].set_xlabel('Irradiance (W/m^2)', fontsize=16)
axs[1][1].set_ylabel('Power (W)', fontsize=16)
add_ax.set_ylabel('Module temperature (Deg. C)', fontsize=16)

for i,j in zip(IV_start_index,IV_start_index[1:]):  # This is simple code to access present and next element in a list
    .
    .
    .

    axs[1][1].plot(module_allData_df['Irradiance'].iloc[i],p_mpp,'go')        

    add_ax.plot(module_allData_df['Irradiance'].iloc[i],module_allData_df['Temperature'].iloc[i],'bo')
    plt.suptitle('A NIST Module %s day normalized IV curves '%(module_allData_df['Time'].loc[i].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),fontsize=18) #         
    plt.savefig('All_day_normalized_IV_plot')
```

Some where, my code is wrong.

I have modified my code as per `@Bazingaa` answer which I accepted below and it solved my problem. Below is the final figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the following line from your code (rest everything remains the same):

```
fig, add_ax = plt.subplots()
```

`add_ax = axs[1][1].twinx()` is sufficient alone and will add a second `y` axis to your bottom, right subplot.

Comment: Initially, I did that. An error popped up saying add_ax not defined. Any other guess?

Comment: If you just do `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(14, 10))` and  `add_ax = axs[1][1].twinx()`, you still get an error? I tried it and it worked without any such error

Comment: I tried this: axs[1][1] = add_ax.twinx() and it gave error.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You should try the other way. In `axs[1][1] = add_ax.twinx()` you assume that `add_ax` already exists and you are now creating a new y-axis `axs[1][1] `. But in reality, you already have `axs[1][1]` and you want to create a second `y` axis in `axs[1][1]`. Therefore you should write `add_ax = axs[1][1].twinx()`

Comment: Now, I am off. I will try it and get back to you tomorrow. Thanks a lot. I am new to python and thank you very much for providing me inputs.

Comment: It worked. Excellent. Thanks for educating me about mistake I did. Yes, I was calling the undeclared axis `add_ax`. That's the reason it was giving error. Now, I understood this. Thanks a lot. I have modified above my question to include this solution.